# How to access Discord Bot token from another python file for Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, discord, global-variables, token

I am trying to set up a Discord Bot on Heroku and in attempting to start it up for the first time, I am realizing that my main python file (main.py) with all the bot's code can't seem to access the variable 'TOKEN' I have set in another .env file (token.env) for the bot's token.

token.env file:

```
TOKEN = [ token goes here ]
```

main.py file (relevant portion):

```
import discord
import os 

from token import TOKEN

token = TOKEN
client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    msg = message.content

    if msg.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')



client.run(token)
```

I researched how to access a variable from another file using python and the syntax said to write

`from file_name import variable_name`

As you can see, I did this in main.py to access the variable TOKEN in token.env but here is the error code I get when I try to run the Heroku bot.

```
app/worker.1 ImportError: cannot import name 'TOKEN' from 'token' (/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/token.py)
```

also, here is my Procfile:

```
worker: python main.py
```

and yes, the bot is turned on in its Heroku dashboard.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Update!: I got ```main.py``` to access the variable from the ```.env``` file! I moved the ```.env``` file to the same directory as the ```main.py``` file and ran 
```token = os.getenv("TOKEN")
print(token)``` .....and it worked! It was able to print the token from another file! Now I just need to figure out how to get "import discord" to stop throwing a "no module named discord" error when I clearly have discord.py installed...smh

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. After installing python-dotenv, and changing the name of my env file to .env, I was still running into problems when trying to print the TOKEN variable in my main.py file. What eventually ended up fixing it was I moved the .env file to the same directory as my main.py script (before .env was in a separate folder). This fixed it and I was able to grab the variable from .env and print it in main.py. Thanks to all who helped me! I have uploaded my final code from main.py and .env.

```
import os 
import dotenv
from dotenv import load_dotenv


load_dotenv()
token = os.getenv('TOKEN')
print(token)
```

and .env

```
TOKEN = qwertyuiopasdfgjklmnbvz
```

Answer (score 0):

The `from... import...` syntax is only valid for python modules saved with the `.py` format. To access variables in `.env` files use:

```py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv("TOKEN")
```

The file should also just be called `.env` not `token.env`.
Note that the `dotenv` module must be installed and this can be done using:

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

Comment: ok, I made your changes but I am getting a different error now...here are the logs:

app/worker.1   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 304, in static_login
app/worker.1     raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
app/worker.1 discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.

It is saying "improper token" but I triple checked and I have the correct bot token in .env

Comment: If the token is wrong then I can't really help you. Maybe try printing out the token variable in your code and checking it is the same as the one in the .env file

Comment: what is the format of the .env file supposed to look like? I have:
TOKEN = [ token ]

Comment: In my `.env` file for my discord bot I have `TOKEN = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm" - make sure you have speech marks. Apart from that it looks OK

Comment: Well, it seems I forgot you have to use `load_dotenv` first. My mistake, sorry. I have edited the answer now.

Comment: I ran "pip install python-dotenv" and it install properly (it shows up in "pip list"), however, now when I add "from dotenv import dotenv" it throws an error because it doesn't recognize "dotenv". :(  I will look into this problem on my own but do you have any tips?